# Why doesn´t this for loop go thought the list?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I´m making a snake game and I need to check for collisions. So I created two methods. First one checks collisions and the other one closes the game etc. I check these collisions every game tick. I use a for loop but it seems as the loop only checks the first item in the body list.

I tried print() to see where the code hiccups. I found out that the for loop goes only thought the first item in the list (self.body_count).

```py
    def collision(self, snake, obs):
        for i in obs:
            if i.x == snake.x and i.y == snake.y:
                print("pre pí")
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def check_coll(self):
        if self.collision(self.snake_head, self.body_count):
            pyglet.app.exit()
```

Comment: You `return` in the first iteration. As soon as a function hits a `return`, it exits the func immediately

Comment: The first time through the loop either the `if` block or the `else` block gets evaluated.  Each has a return statement so you only ever check the first element of `obs`.  Instead remove the `else` and de-indent `return False` to get the behavior you want.

Comment: BTW, you can collapse `i.x == snake.x and i.y == snake.y` into `(i.x, i.y) == (snake.x, snake.y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning in the first iteration. Instead what you should be doing is the following:

```
def collision(self, snake, obs):
        for i in obs:
            if i.x == snake.x and i.y == snake.y:
                print("pre pí")
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: Or one can turn it into a generator by changing `return` into `yield`. Then `if self.collision(self.snake_head, self.body_count)` would change into `if any(self.collision(self.snake_head, self.body_count))`

Answer (score 0):

Because you're returning inside the loop.

A possible solution might be:

```
def collision(self, snake, obs):
    did_collide = False
    for i in obs:
        if i.x != snake.x and i.y != snake.y:
            return True

    return did_collide
```